Probability density function that satisfies an ODE
Let $k_1<0, k_2$ be two real numbers. Does there exist a probability density function $p(x), x\in\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the second-order ODE $$xp(x)=k_1p'(x)+k_2p''(x)$$
When $k_2=0$, it is clear that the Gaussian distribution satisfies the ODE. However, it is less clear to me what is the case when $k_2\neq 0$. More generally, I am also curious about if there exists $p(x)$ that satisfies $$xp(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m k_i p^{(i)}(x)$$ for some $k_i, i=1,2,\cdots, m$.
Finally, if such density exists, is it possible to obtain a lower bound of it in terms of the Gaussian density $\phi(x)$?
I have tried to write $p(x)$ in terms of the Gram–Charlier A series and build a recursive relation of the coefficients. However, it seems challenging to examine the positivity of the solution. I'm wondering if there is any literature that studies densities of this type.

For $0 < x < \infty$ there are solutions involving the Airy function $\operatorname{Ai}$ that look promising.

@Aruralreader Thanks for the remark! I can see that the ODE reduces to an Airy equation with some change of variables. However I think this approach does not work for $m \geq 3$.
